# ValueError: logits and labels must have the same shape ((None, 1) vs ())

Tags: python, tensorflow, nlp, lstm, valueerror

I am getting a ValueError: logits and labels must have the same shape ((None, 1) vs ()) when doing a model evaluate. I get the model to train but when I evaluate is when I have the problem. I used a tf.expand_dims for logits but wondering if this needs to be applied to the labels as well?

here is my code below.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
```

```
dataset, info = tfds.load('imdb_reviews', with_info=True,
                          as_supervised=True)
train_dataset, test_dataset = dataset['train'], dataset['test']
```

```
BUFFER_SIZE = 10000
BATCH_SIZE = 64
```

```
train_dataset = train_dataset.shuffle(BUFFER_SIZE).batch(BATCH_SIZE).prefetch(1)
```

```
VOCAB_SIZE, EMBED_SIZE, NUM_OOV_BUCKETS = 10000, 128, 1000
```

```
encoder = tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.TextVectorization(
    max_tokens=VOCAB_SIZE)
encoder.adapt(train_dataset.map(lambda text, label: text))
```

```
class AttentionLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):

        super(AttentionLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.query_layer = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(
            filters=100,
            kernel_size=4,
            padding='same'
        )

        self.value_layer = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(
            filters=100,
            kernel_size=4,
            padding='same'
        )

        self.attention_layer = tf.keras.layers.Attention()
    
    def call(self, inputs):

        query = self.query_layer(inputs)
        value = self.value_layer(inputs)

        attention = self.attention_layer([query, value])

        return tf.keras.layers.concatenate([query, attention])

attention_layer = AttentionLayer()
```

```
model1 = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.Input(shape=(),batch_size=1, dtype=tf.string, name='InputLayer'),
    encoder,
    tf.keras.layers.Embedding(VOCAB_SIZE + NUM_OOV_BUCKETS, EMBED_SIZE, mask_zero=True, name='Embedding_Layer'),
    attention_layer,
    tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=32, kernel_size=4, padding = 'same', activation = 'relu', name='Conv1DLayer'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2, name='MaxPoolLayer'),
    tf.keras.layers.LSTM(64, dropout = 0.2, name='DropoutLayer'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(250, activation = 'relu', name='DenseLayer'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name='Output_Layer')
])
```

```
model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", optimizer="adam", metrics=["accuracy"])
```

```
def preprocess_y(x, y):
    return x, tf.expand_dims(y, -1)
```

```
history1 = model1.fit(
    train_dataset.map(preprocess_y),
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
    epochs=1)
```

```
model1.evaluate(test_dataset)
```

ValueError: logits and labels must have the same shape ((None, 1) vs ())

Comment: You never prepared the `test_dataset`. Do test_dataset = test_dataset.batch(1).prefect(1) like you did to your training data.

Comment: That would work. I don't think I asked the question correctly where I need the input shape to be (None) or () as this is the requirement for an autograder to test the model performance on the test set.